# Sticky footer with bootstrap 3.x not working

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

I am trying to implement the sticky footer for bootstrap but it is not working for me. I have a header.php and a footer.php which I include in every page of my website. I saw a various posts here for the sticky footer but it doesn't seem to work for me. I saw an example to add a  and a  to the body of my page and modify the css accordingly but it doesnt seem to work. Please find my code below:

webpage.php

```
<?php
require_once "../includes/essentials.php";
include "../includes/header.php";
?>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="main" class="container">
   Content


<?php include "../includes/footer.php"; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Footer.php

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="footer">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                 Content
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                 Content
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                Compatible with <a href="http://www.firefox.com">Firefox</a> and <a href="http://www.chrome.com">Chrome</a>.
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 1000px;
}

.main {
  overflow:auto;
  padding-bottom:200px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 150px;
  clear:both;
  padding-top:20px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

How do i fix this? I want the footer to stick at the bottom of the page even if content gets over before half of the webpage.

Comment: Do you have an example with the `.main` and `.wrap` elements included?

Comment: @pstenstrm - edited the code to reflect the format of `.main` and `.wrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS you select `.main` as a class but in the html you've put is as an ID `<div id="main">`.

Secondly the `<div class="footer">` should be outside of `#wrap`, as a sibling and not a child.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        // <div id="contnainer"...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    // <div id="contnainer"...
</div>
```

Comment: what about the wrap div? @pstenstrm

Comment: Right, sorry. Edited my answer

Comment: It pushes the footer to the below of the page when there is no content but overlaps when there is content on the page. @pstenstrm

Comment: That's because you have `wrap` and `main` as id's in the html. You eiter have to change those to classes or change the css selectors to `#main {}` and `#wrap {}`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to your problem is to use a NavBar as a footer, and simply fill it with the content you'd like in it.

Bootstrap Components provides the JS for the NavBar to stick to the top or bottom of the screen.

You can read about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom)